# In MS-Access, where does the data actually gets filtered?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

In my MS-Access project, I have spitted the database into front and back end. The back end is on the shared network drive. The front end contains all the forms, modules and queries. The back end just contains all of my tables.

I have queries that make use of functions which I defined inside the modules of the front end MS-access file. I use those functions to filter out data in the way I want. So does that mean data is filtered on the front end ?

Also when I use predefined SQL functions like AVG or COUNT or MAX, is it the back end that already filters the data or is it my front end that gets the whole table and than filters the data?

Would the situation change if I host my back end to an actual Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a COMMON myth that Access pulls the whole tables.
In the case of a file based (accDB) back end on a network, then access ONLY pulls the records WHEN an index can be used. So if you have a table of 1 million records, and build a query that retunes ONE customer, then only that one customer is pulled from that table (assuming an index is available). In fact how this works does not matter if the table is on your local computer, or on some network drive. Access in BOTH cases will read a tiny part of the index, and then seek to the correct part of the file and pull the one record. If no index is available, then a full table scan occurs.

And the same goes if the back end if SQL server. Once again, an access query (or form) based on that table with criteria will ONLY pull down the one row of data – not the whole table. And in this case, an index is not required. If no index is available, then a full table scan will occur on SQL server, and WHEN it finds the one row – that row is sent to the client.
For file based back end then no real processing occurs on the server (all it does is “read” the file like a dumb disk drive). So Access simply “sees” that as a file sitting on a disk drive. Since Access does not read + pull in the full table when that file is local, or sitting on some server drive, then how this works does not change.

Access is NOT reading in the full table into memory when an index can be used. The fact that the table is on a local drive, a USB jump drive, or some server drive does NOT change how Access works.

Access simply does not read the whole table when an index is available – the location of the file does not change this process in anyway. So no real processing occurs on the server for the file – the file is just read from disk based on the commands from Access to read bits and parts of that file based on an index.

I should also point out that the above process DOES NOT require a pass-though query when working with SQL server. You can open a form bound to a linked table to SQL server with 1 million rows - if you launch that form with a "where" clause that the openform command provides , then only the 1 record traverses the network pipe - again no pass-though query is required even for forms bound directly to linked tables to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an AVG in MS Access, it calculates the average (uses CPU cycles) on the *client side*. If you run an AVG on SQL Server it calcs it on the server side (assuming you write your MS Access query correctly). MS Access cannot push any processing off to a server as it is a client side program. It is smart enough to only get the parts of the remote file that it needs, but it can't offload processing anywhere.

If for example your query only filters on the *result* of your custom function, there is no way for MS Access to pre-evaluate and filter the custom function on the client side. There is no MS-Access process on the server running your custom functions. Everything executes on the client side.